# How to take incremental backup of a large file (100GB) with rsync?

Tags: linux, diff, rsync

I have a scenario where I have to take an incremental backup every 5 minutes of a large file which is around 100GB on the local machine if the content of the file changes.

> Filename: example.txt
>
> Backups: example.txt.00:05, example.txt.00:10, example.txt.00:15 and
>   so on.

What will be the most optimized way to do this?

If I opt for diff than it will take a lot of time to check the content of the file.

I would prefer doing it with rsync but I am unsure about how it will manage the multiple files.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out with the man page of rsync.

> -b, --backup  make backups (see --suffix & --backup-dir)
>
> --backup-dir=DIR make backups into hierarchy based in DIR
>
> --suffix=SUFFIX         backup suffix (default ~ w/o --backup-dir)

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while True
do
timestamp=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
echo $timestamp
rsync -avschz --backup --backup-dir=archive --suffix="-$timestamp" example.txt backup
sleep 300
done
```

The above script will create an archive directory inside the backup directory and rename the files accordingly.

Output:

```
imohit:rsync-script ethicalmohit$ ls -l backup/archive/
total 88064
-rw-r--r--  1 ethicalmohit  staff  18874368 Mar 25 03:06 example.txt-03:15:41
-rw-r--r--  1 ethicalmohit  staff  12582912 Mar 25 03:17 example.txt-03:25:42
-rw-r--r--  1 ethicalmohit  staff  13631488 Mar 25 03:25 example.txt-03:30:42
```